# OR for a single taxonomy in a tax_query

Tags: tax-query

I have a `tax_query` that has a value added like this:

```php
$query->query_vars['tax_query'][] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'location',
    'include_children' => true,
    'field' => 'county',
    'terms' => array($_REQUEST['s-location']),
    'operator' => 'IN'
);
```

And I would now like to add this as a `OR` to the above. The overall relation for the `tax_query` still needs to be `AND`, but I'd just like this taxonomy to be with an `OR` in between. How could I achieve this?

```php
$query->query_vars['tax_query'][] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'location',
    'include_children' => true,
    'field' => "JSON_EXTRACT(ads_value, '$.paadress')",
    'terms' => '%'.$cname.'%',
    'operator' => 'LIKE'
);
```

Comment: Does these query_vars work? Just want to understand the logic here. You have location taxonomy where terms have meta fields - country and address. You want to recieve posts if some countries equal to your values OR with some addresses equal to your values. If it's true, I think you need to use both tax_query and meta_query. If I remember right, field parameter of tax_query should be just a column name in taxonomy table, which are `term_id, slug, name or term_taxonomy_id`.

Comment: @anton Separately, yes they work. We're in the middle of an address system migration and this query needs to return objects where one of these matches. Either the old system (county field) is set to an id, or the address value has a match to the search word..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the comments you said:

> We're in the middle of an address system migration and this query
> needs to return objects where one of these matches. Either the old
> system (county field) is set to an id, or the address value has a
> match to the search word

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/__construct/), custom term fields like the `county` and `ads_value` (or `JSON_EXTRACT()`) in your case are not supported, and the `LIKE` is also not a standard value for `operator`; however, since you said that "*Separately, yes they work.*", then let's assume you've got some custom code which handle those custom fields and operator?

And I think all that you need to do is place those two conditions/clauses into a single clause with an `OR` relation like so:

```php
$tax_query = (array) ( $query->query_vars['tax_query'] ?? array() );

// Add a (named) top-level clause with an OR relation.
$tax_query['location'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
);

// Sub-clause 1: Search in the 'county' field.
// *You should check if $_REQUEST['s-location'] is set.
$tax_query['location'][] = array(
    'taxonomy'         => 'location',
    'include_children' => true,
    'field'            => 'county',
    'terms'            => array( $_REQUEST['s-location'] ),
    'operator'         => 'IN',
);

// Sub-clause 2: Search in the ads_value field.
$tax_query['location'][] = array(
    'taxonomy'         => 'location',
    'include_children' => true,
    'field'            => "JSON_EXTRACT(ads_value, '$.paadress')",
    'terms'            => '%' . $cname . '%',
    'operator'         => 'LIKE',
);

$query->query_vars['tax_query'] = $tax_query;

/* Or short version:
$query->query_vars['tax_query'][] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',

    // sub-clause 1
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
        'field'    => 'county',
        'terms'    => array( $_REQUEST['s-location'] ),
        'operator' => 'IN',

    ),

    // sub-clause 2
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
        'field'    => "JSON_EXTRACT(ads_value, '$.paadress')",
        'terms'    => '%' . $cname . '%',
        'operator' => 'LIKE',
    ),
);
*/
```

Or did I get it wrong? If so, let me know and I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: This and a fix to the code handling the tax query to perform the DB search for me, worked wonderfully.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, but by "short version", I was also referring to using the default values such as `IN` for the `operator`, so I intentionally omitted the `'operator' => 'IN'` because the default is `IN`.. anyway, thanks for the initial edit. :)